# ch++ works but ch = ch + 1 requires explicit cast to char. Why?

Tags: java

Consider the following piece of code

```
char ch1 = 'A';
ch1 = ch1 + 1;

char ch2 = 'B';
ch2++;
```

The below line results in compilation error: ***cannot convert from int to char***.
I understand that char is promoted to int when used in expression and that is why we have to explicitly cast the RHS to char to make this work

```
ch1 = ch1 + 1;
```

But, the line below gets compiled successfully. Is this not an expression?

```
ch2++;
```

What is the logic to explain this?

Comment: Fwiw, `ch += 1` would work too.

Answer (score 0):

The binary + operator gives an int result. This cannot be assigned to a char variable without a cast. This is defined in the JLS:

Widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2) is applied to convert either or both operands as specified by the following rules:

- If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double.
- If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double.
- Otherwise, if either operand is of type float, the other is converted to float.
- Otherwise, if either operand is of type long, the other is converted to long.
- Otherwise, both operands are converted to type int.

The `ch2++;` does not suffer from the same conversions.